# DNSの挙動について

Tags: dns

お聞きしたい内容は、
同サーバー内でメールの送受信を行った場合、一般的な接続と異なる挙動をする可能性はあるのでしょうか。
また、同サーバー内間のメールの送受信でルートが変わるのであれば、強制的にルートサーバーを経由させる方法はあるのでしょうか。
もし参考になるURLや書籍があれば伺いたいです。
という内容です。

以下に詳細を記述します。

現在、XSERVERで2つのドメインを管理しています。
example.comとexample.netとし、サーバー名をxsrvとします。

example.com、example.net共にXSERVERをメールサーバーとしているのですが、
example.comの一部のアドレス（gsuite@example.comとします）のみ、GSuiteで運用をしています。

example.comのDNSの設定は
ドメインからxsrvへNSレコード設定
xsrvから、MXレコードでxsrv内のメールサーバーと、GSuiteのサーバーを振り分け
となっています。

この状態で、xsrv外とはメールのやり取りがうまいく行くのですが、xsrv内のメールアドレスと、gsuite@example.com間でのメールのやり取りができておらず、解決方法を探しています。

今回はこのような内容でつまりましたが、最近DNS関連で詰まることが多いので、役に立つ情報があれば知りたいと思っています。

よろしくお願いいたします。

-----2017年7月21日 9時11分 補足-----
コメントや返信ありがとうございます。

SMTPの問題は盲点でした。言われてみれば詳しく知らないので、調べてみたいと思います。

MXレコードについては、以下のようになっています。
**xsrvのDNSレコード**
example.com A   000.00.000.00（xsrvのIP）
mail.example.com A   000.00.000.00（xsrvのIP）
example.com  MX  ALT2.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM 5
example.com  MX  ALT3.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM 10
example.com  MX  ALT1.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM 5
example.com  MX  ALT4.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM
example.com  MX  ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.C
mail.example.com MX  example.com 20

上記の設定でxsrv内にアドレスが存在しない場合は、GSuiteへ送られる認識でおりました。

Comment: DNSというかSMTPに関する問題のように見受けられますね。STMPに関する書籍など読んでみると良いのではないでしょうか。

Comment: 「xsrvから、MXレコードでxsrv内のメールサーバーと、GSuiteのサーバーを振り分け」というのはどういった MX レコードで実現されていますか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

xsrvのメールサーバ(sendmailとかpostfixとか)ではexample.comは最終到達先として設定されているはずですから、xsrvがgsuite@example.com宛てのメールを受け取ればサーバ内にユーザーがいるものとして処理しようとします。一部のユーザが別のサーバにいるのであれば、それらのユーザーについてそのサーバに向けて転送する設定をxsrvのメールサーバでおこなう必要があります。

--

> 上記の設定でxsrv内にアドレスが存在しない場合は、GSuiteへ送られる認識でおりました。

優先度がGoogleの方が高いので全てのメールはGoogleに配送されるでしょう。GSuiteでの未登録ユーザーへの配送は500番台のエラーになるはずなのでフォールバックは起きないはずです。

複雑なことはやめて、G Suiteではexample.com、xsrvではsub.example.comのように扱うメールのドメインを分割することをお勧めします。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。やはりxsrv内でGsuiteと同じメールアカウントを作成し、xsrv内で受け取ってから処理（転送）させる必要があるのですね。ありがとうございます！

Comment: DNSの話では、MXレコードの優先度が高い方から送り、送れない場合は次の優先度が高いMXレコードに送る。という話を見ていたため、勘違いをしていたようです。メールサーバーに届いてしまうと500番エラーで配送完了扱いになるのですね……
今回質問でメールサーバーの知識が足りていないことがわかりましたので、勉強しようと思います。ありがとうございました！（なぜか、勝手に保存扱いになるため何度も通知が届いていたらすみません）

Comment: MXフォールバックの「大まかな動作」はその通りなのですが、厳密な動作は定められていませんのでMTAの実装次第です。すべてのMXを試すとは限りませんしフォールバックしないものもあります。フォールバックが起きる事を前提にするのは一般にまずい設計です。(そもそも、期待する動作から見ると優先度が間違っているのですが